# How to handle many jpa entities in one request (OpenSessionInView)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

we have classic Spring application with OpenSessionInView pattern.

Sometimes we want proces many (=unknown size) entities in one request.
This is well-known OutOfMemory issue.

Long time ago, we create function(hack) to switch current hibernate session for particular method.

```
public void proceedOnePerson(int id) {
    recalculateVAT(id);
}

public void proceedAllPerson(int[] ids) {
    for(int id : ids) {
        switchToAnotherHibernateSesion();
        recalculateVAT(id); //OutOfMemory
        closeAnotherSessionAndSwitchBackToOriginSession();
    }
}
```

**Is there standard solution to this in Spring, Spring Boot or Spring Data?**

- Session.clear is not suitable, because has side effect on other entities from other methods.
- Session.evict is not suitable too, because developer of method recalculateVAT had no idea if this function will be used in batch. Error prone.
- Spring batch is too heavy. And we dont want to write one method for user and second method for batch.

Comment: Why wouldn't evict work... Basically that is what you are doing now also. You are opening a new session for each read which is generally slow.

Comment: Simple this isn't true. Opening new session is lightweight and very fast operation. Evict every single entity is not possible for many reasons.

Comment: Well that depends on what you say is fast, opening a session involves claiming a connection, starting a transaction. Both of them are quite slow in comparision to the remainder of your method functions.

Comment: Opening new hibernate session not open new connection to database and do nothing with transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use  Open Session in view pattern, performance of this pattern is very poor, and view layer is nos prepared to manage hibernate or other jpa implement exception. Why don't you use spring data with a service layer transforming pojos objects to dto to be consumed by view layer?

OutOfMemory is typicall when you use this pattern when you are getting a lot of data información with multiples queries, if you do not use this patter this problem will disapear.